# R histogram breaks Error

Tags: r, algorithm, histogram

I have to prepare an algorithm for my thesis to cross check a theoretical result which is that the binomial model for N periods converges to lognormal distribution for N\to \infty. For those of you not familiar with the concept i have to create an algorithm that takes a starter value and multiplies it with an up-multiplier and a down multiplier and continues to do so for every value for N steps. The algorithm should return a vector whose elements are in the form of StarterValue*u^i*d^{N-i} i=0,\dots,N
the simple algorithm i proposed is

```
rata<-function(N,r,u,d,S){

  length(x)<-N
  for(i in 0:N){
    x[i]<-S*u^{i}*d^{N-i}
  }
  return(x)
}
```

N is the number of periods and the rest are just nonimportant values (u is for the up d for down etc)
In order to extract my results i need to make a histogram of the produced vector's logarithm to prove that they are normally distributed. However for a N=100000( i need an  great number of steps to prove convergence) when i type `hist(x)` i get the `error :(invalid number of breaks)`
Can anyone help?? thanks in advance. 
An example

```
 taf<-rata(100000,1,1.1,0.9,1)
 taf1<-log(taf)
 hist(taf1,xlim=c(-400,400))
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, i.e., code that calls this function and produces a histogram (resulting in this error). Also, a simulation can't "prove convergence".

Comment: yes you are correct the algorithm is there as another showcase of the convergence the actual proof happens before that . As for the example i updated the question however i dont know why i cant make it to be in code format

Comment: Your example errors, because the result vector `taf1` only contains -Inf, Inf and NaN. So there's no actual numbers to make a histogram with.

Comment: i see that now but why does that happen? i can understand the inf,-inf but i cannot understand the NaNs.

Comment: Not the logaritm, the algorithm. taf only contains 0's and Inf. And on a clean environment your function errors, because x is not defined. Better approach is to just use a vectorized approach (i <- 1:N; x <- S*u^{i}*d^{N-i}) but that doesn't solve your issue that your algorithm cannot deal with the large numbers it produces. I always struggle with large integers in R.

Comment: And you cannot calculate the log of -Inf.

Comment: thanks alot i understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I fix your function:

```
rata<-function(N,r,u,d,S){
  x <- numeric(N+1)
  for(i in 0:N){
    x[i]<-S*u^{i}*d^{N-i}
  }
  return(x)
}
```

Or relying on vectorization:

```
rata<-function(N,r,u,d,S){
  x<-S*u^{0:N}*d^{N-(0:N)}
  return(x)
}

taf<-rata(100000,1,1.1,0.9,1)
```

Looking at the result, we notice that it contains `NaN` values:

```
taf[7440 + 7:8]
#[1]   0 NaN
```

What happened? Apparently the multiplication became `NaN`:

```
1.1^7448*0.9^(1e5-7448)
#[1] NaN

1.1^7448
#[1] Inf

0.9^(1e5-7448)
#[1] 0

Inf * 0
#[1] NaN
```

Why does an `Inf` value occur? Well, because of double overflow (read `help("double")`):

```
1.1^(7440 + 7:8)
#[1] 1.783719e+308           Inf
```

You have a similar problem with floating point precision when a multiplicant gets close to 0 (read `help(".Machine")`).

You may need to use arbitrary precision numbers.